# inner class extended by another inner class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, inner-classes, super

Error occur when `class C extends B`. But, when I write `new A().super();` problem is solved. Please consider following code:

```
 public class A {
        public class B extends A {
            public class C extends B {
                public C() {
                    // No enclosing instance of type A is available due to some intermediate constructor error
                    // new A().super();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is why `class C cannot extend Class B`? Why calling `new A().super();` solved the problem? What does it mean? Is there better way to solve it (without using static nested class)?

Comment: Both versions (with and without `new A().super();` compile just fine for me. I am running java 1.8.0_144.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "Error occur" and "problem"?

Comment: Regarding "better way to solve it", I would consider refactoring the nested class hierachy into separate classes, but of course it depends on what the real code is modeling.

Comment: @Henry error -> No enclosing instance of type A is available due to some intermediate constructor

Comment: 'Non-static inner' is a tautology.

Comment: @Turing85 Are your sure? Did you create nested class or two classes within one file?

Comment: @Alice I copy-pasted your code. One file. I am quite confident that the problem lies elsewhere (i.e. if you try to instantiate a `C`). Take a look at [Kostiantyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46235115/4216641).

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I try to understand his answer, but I am not still clear about new A().super();

Comment: @Alice please show the exact compile error message, as well as the relevant code leading to the error. The code you showed on its own is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest code snippet which will be compiled and executed printing 'OK':

```
    public class A {
        public class B extends A {
            public class C extends B {
                public C() {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           new A().new B().new C();
        }
    }
```

Here is another [example](https://pastebin.com/7cc2uW7u) of instantiation of A, B and C. That is, **class C can extend Class B** as of initial code snippet from your question. Your code is correct in terms of syntax, and can be compiled without adding any unnecessary `new A().super()`

For consideration, let's refer to the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for *inner classes*, those by definition are non-static. For static case the correct name is *static nested class*

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class

That means, that inner class exists only in context of particular OuterClass instance rather than OuterClass class, that's why `new A()` does solve the problem, providing runtime *instance* within which *classes* `B` and `C` do exist

Comment: calling new A() does not solve the problem. Calling new A().super(); solved the problem. Please explain me what is the output of calling it?

Comment: @Alice the tutorial is right there. Did you read it? Calling `new A().super();` instructs the compiler to create a new instance of `A` and then calls the super-constructor (of `C`, i.e. the constructor of `B`) on that `A` (hence the `.super()`-part). Thus, the `C` instance binds to the newly created `A` instance.

Comment: @Turing85 I agree a new instance of A calls the super-constructor, but I don't think A super is C.

Comment: @Alice the `super` is interpreted relative to `C`, not to `A` and thus calls `B`'s constructor.

Comment: Can you please share entire piece of code which is not compiled correctly? Consider this [paste](https://pastebin.com/pLzhHKXh) which compiles successfully and prints 'OK', as well as [this one](https://pastebin.com/7cc2uW7u). So please add that part that does not compile.